# SQL Server : Query Missing FROM clause with IIf

Tags: sql, iif, ms-query

I need to run a T-SQL query via the Microsoft Query interface, using an `IIf` statement.

When I run the query, I get the error `Missing FROM clause`. This is odd, because the `FROM` clause is there. It fails because of the `IIf` but I have no idea why.

The code:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.NUMBER, 
    TABLE1.TEXT, 
    TABLE1.INT, 
    IIf(
        (
            (
                ((TABLE2.INT1-TABLE2.INT2) -TABLE2.INT3) -TABLE2.INT4
            ) > 0
        ), 
        (
            1
        ),  0) 
        as NEWCOL
FROM 
    DB.TABLEX TABLE1, 
    DB.TABLEY TABLE2
WHERE 
    TABLE2.NUMBER = TABLE1.NUMBER 
    AND TABLE1.NUMBER='991208000192'
```

The database is not mine, so I have to work with what I can. Does anyone have an idea what may cause the problem?

Comment: what rdbms are you using? I believe `IIf` is only available in SQL Server 2012, and it is also an MS-Access function.

Comment: @bluefeet I am not sure what rdbms it is using since I have really, really limited access. I have tried `CASE`, but then I found out that the server does not use that statement.

Comment: You have so many redundant parenthesis that this `IIf` statement is not very clear. Maybe it generates this syntax error?

Comment: You are going to need to determine what database you have.  That will then allow you to use the correct functions.

Comment: @bluefeet I have made a call and they told me it is SQLBase, but they didn't know the version.. Is that of any help? If the `IIf` and `Case` functions can't be used, how can I do this query then?

Comment: Try using an IF .. ELSE statement instead of IIF, (According to this): http://enos.itcollege.ee/~priit/(I216)%20Ab-de%20administreerimine/SQLBase%20admin%20juhendid/LANG.PDF

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I've tried this, but Microsoft Query returns `Invalid Column Expression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the SQLBase reference in http://enos.itcollege.ee/~priit/(I216)%20Ab-de%20administreerimine/SQLBase%20admin%20juhendid/LANG.PDF (Courtesy @twoleggedhorse) does not have function IIF in SQLBase. It has a function IF with similar syntax as your IIF.

Try using @IF(CONDITION, TRUE_VAL, FALSE_VAL) in your SQL.